# Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`: ! geom_dotplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y

Tags: r, ggplot2

The problem is that whilst I try to plot using geom_dotplot, I receive the error:

```
 Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
! geom_dotplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

The data for this problem is:

```
sum.qmerge<-structure(list(absdif = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 
0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01
), landscape = c("cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random")), row.names = c(NA, 
-147L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code I am using to plot this data is:

```
ggplot(sum.qmerge)+geom_dotplot(aes(x = landscape, y = absdif),dotsize=0.5,binwidth = 0.2)+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)+
  xlab("Landscape Type")+
  ylab("Absolute Difference")
```

I have tried adding the aesthetic function to both ggplot() and geom_dotplot() but I keep receiving the error. What is the solution? Many thanks.

Comment: The error does not show up when x = absdif and y = landscape.

Comment: Try `geom_dotplot(..., , binaxis = "y")` if you want your categories on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `dotplot` by adjusting the `binaxis` and `stackdir` options:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sum.qmerge <- structure(list(absdif = c(
  0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,
  0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,
  0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01,
  0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,
  0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01,
  0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.01,
  0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01,
  0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02,
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02,
  0.02, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,
  0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.01,
  0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01
), landscape = c(
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster",
  "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular",
  "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random",
  "random", "random", "random", "random", "random"
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -147L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(sum.qmerge, aes(landscape, absdif)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.2) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  xlab("Landscape Type") +
  ylab("Absolute Difference")
#> Bin width defaults to 1/30 of the range of the data. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>